# Creating a "fake" disk on windows that actually goes to a remote disk

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a seagate harddrive connected to my router. I can get to my files but i cannot use the file location in phpstorm. I can edit the files but the file tree is not showing. I read that you could "create a fake harddrive" on windows so that windows lists it as a harddrive for example J:. This way i guess it could work in phpstorm.

So the question is: how do i do this or is it even possible?

I need this "cloud" because i use different computers in the network

Comment: I think this question belongs to a different site ([su]).

Comment: Working with project files directly over network is NOT recommended by PhpStorm devs as this IDE requires fast access to the source files -- any slowdowns (network latency is usually much higher compared to local SSD or even HDD) most likely will result sin short freezes and similar effects out of nowhere (e.g. when using code completion etc).

Comment: In any case -- you can use "drive mount" -- standard Windows feature when network share is given the drive letter -- it works for sure; You may need to restart IDE .. or you may have issues with UAC (e.g. need to run it as Administrator maybe)

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `net use Z: \\192.168.1.2\sharename`, but that would only work on a NAS with a shared folder on it.

Comment: You can also make a "volume mount point."